# Function to check if the first character of a string is a letter

Tags: php, regex

I made this function to check if the first character is a letter.

```
function isLetter($string) {
  return preg_match('/^\s*[a-z,A-Z]/', $string) > 0;
}
```

However, if I check a sentence that starts with a  coma (`,`) the functions returns `true`. What is the proper regex to check if the first letter is a-z or A-Z?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to remove the comma:

```
'/^\s*[a-zA-Z]/'
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly cleaner way, in my opinion. Just makes the code a little more human readable.

```
function isLetter($string) {
    return preg_match('/^[a-z]/i', trim($string));
}
```